# Returning element from a 2D array (type error)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Trying to code an accessor for my 2D array class Matrix3D however the compiler is giving me issues on c-style code which I would expect to work fine in this context. The error in question is

> error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const T [3]' to 'const T'

When using my accessors:

```
    const T operator()(eMatrix3D::eMatrix3DElements) const
    T operator()(eMatrix3D::eMatrix3DElements)
```

Would love to get some feedback on the root cause of the issue and also so feedback on how to make my code compatible with `std::array<std::array<T, 3>, 3> m_elem` instead of `T m_elem[3][3]` and what are the differences to look out for?

Please find sample code below:

```
namespace eMatrix3D {
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** ENUMS ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    enum eMatrix3DElements
    {
        e11 = 0,
        e12,
        e13,
        e21,
        e22,
        e23,
        e31,
        e32,
        e33
    };
}

template <typename T>
class Matrix3D
{
public:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** CONSTRUCTORS ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// Default Constructor
    //
    Matrix3D(void);

    /// External initialization Constructor
    //
    Matrix3D(const T& p_11, const T& p_12, const T& p_13,
             const T& p_21, const T& p_22, const T& p_23,
             const T& p_31, const T& p_32, const T& p_33);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** DESTRUCTOR ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// Destructor
    //
    ~Matrix3D(void);
    ...
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // *** PUBLIC METHODS (Accessors) ***
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// Get matrix m_element
    /// \note 1-indexed
    //
    const T operator()(eMatrix3D::eMatrix3DElements) const;
    /// Get matrix m_elem (non-const version)
    /// \note 1-indexed
    //
    T operator()(eMatrix3D::eMatrix3DElements);
    ...
private:
    /// Matrix m_elements
    //
    T m_elem[3][3]; //std::array<std::array<T, 3>, 3> m_elem;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// *** PUBLIC METHODS (Accessors) ***
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/// Get matrix m_elem
/// \note 1-indexed
//
template <typename T>
const T Matrix3D<T>::operator()(eMatrix3D::eMatrix3DElements index) const
{
    return *(m_elem + index);
}


/// Get matrix m_elem (non-const version)
/// \note 1-indexed
//
template <typename T>
T Matrix3D<T>::operator()(eMatrix3D::eMatrix3DElements index)
{
    return *(m_elem +index);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use two indices to index the matrix (`m_elem[i][j]`)? It seems like you want to do this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use an `enum` (btw. consider using `enum class`) for your index and your storage is private, why not using a one-dimensional array/vector?

If you take a step back you basically want to access your coordinates `e11` etc. with indexes like `Matrix3D.get(1,1)`. Here the mapping is trivial. Then people usally want to work with a single dimension structure and translate their indexes `i,j` into something like `i*<size_of_first_dimension> + j`, to still keep the 2D interface. Now you already want to have it accessible with a single index, which you provide through your `enum`. This actually does already this meaningful translation for your, so I don't see a reason why you would work with a 2D structure internally. It just makes it more complex.

If you really want to keep 2D internally you need to convert your 1D enum index back into meaningful 2D indexes using division and modulo, or you hard code `switch-case` based on it.

Besides I would rather use `operator[]` or a dedicated `at()` method, rather than the `operator()`, as this is usually associated with function calls and construction (which is a function call to the constructor function). This might confuse you and users of your `Matrix3D` in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some facts.

- `*(m_elem + index)` is exactly the same as `m_elem[index]`, by the definition of the subscript operator.
- `m_elem` is an array of arrays of `T`. It is not the same as an array of `T`.
- Elements of `m_elem` are arrays of `T`. `*(m_elem + index)` or `m_elem[index]`, which is the same exact thing, is one such element. It is an array of `T`, which is not the same as `T`.

If you want `m_elem` to be a linear array of 9 `T` elements, then you should declare it this way, and access it with a single subscript operator. If you want it to be an array of 3 arrays of 3 `T` elements, you can extract individual `T`s by using two subscript operators in a row. But you cannot mix and match pieces of both approaches.

This holds equally for built-in arrays, `std::array`s and other array-like containers.